# mariadb for update doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I was testing mariadb for update with python mysqldb and it doesn't works correctly for me. The same rows are getting twice when running two python scripts symultaneously as cronjob. When I testing on two mysql consoles everything going fine. Using innodb. My code:

```
cursor.execute("start transaction")
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM t1 where tw1=2 AND tw2=1 AND tw3=3 order by id limit 1000 FOR UPDATE")
rows = [r for r in cursor.fetchall()]
ids = []
for row in rows:
    ids.append(str(row['id']))

for i in range(2):

        cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM t2 where tw1="sth" AND tw2 =0 AND tw3=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE")
        d = cursor.fetchone()
        if not d:
           #here: insert to t2 and get last id as d_id

           cursor.execute("update t2 SET tu1=1,tu2=500,tu3=0 WHERE id = %s" % d_id)

            for row in rows:
                #job with rows

cursor.execute( "Update t1 SET tw1=tw1+1 WHERE id IN (" + ','.join(ids) + ")")
cursor.execute("commit")
```

tw1 from t1 should be max 3 but it is very often 4. When I put ids to file I see that there are the same ids for 2 diffrent program runs. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's `tx_isolation`?